# Syntax error in gettext.php library saying "unexpected '!=' (T_IS_NOT_EQUAL)"

Tags: php, php-gettext

I am using the library [gettext.php](https://launchpad.net/php-gettext) (not the standard php_gettext extension) and the error

> PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '!=' (T_IS_NOT_EQUAL) in /base/data/home/apps/.../libs/gettext/gettext.php(387) : eval()'d code on line 1
>   PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: -1 in /base/data/home/apps/.../libs/gettext/gettext.php on line 422

keeps appearing on the following line:

```
$taskCount = Group::activeTaskCount($db, $class[Database::FIELD_CLASS_ID]);
echo ngettext(
        '%d pending task',
        '%d pending tasks',
        $taskCount);
```

The function `Group::activeTaskCount()` performs an SQL query and returns a `COUNT(*)` of a query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that `$taskCount` was actually not returning an integer value, but rather `NULL`. And the `gettext.php` library could not handle this and threw this error.

I changed the code to

```
echo ngettext(
        '%d pending task',
        '%d pending tasks',
        $taskCount ?: 0);
```

so as to foresee the `NULL` case.